# NPM packages not getting installed in Windows-10 from Artifactory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, npm, node-modules

**Issue Description:** I use Artifactory for my NPM packages. While trying to install them in "Windows - 7", it's working fine. But in "Windows - 10" it's showing error and packages are not getting installed.

**Error:**
npm ERR! 403 forbidden 
nmp ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.

**Version:**

Node- 14.15.5
npm- 6.14.11

**Note:**

1. Using NVM for managing node
2. .npmrc: Authentication and registry updated.
3. Packages are getting installed in Windows - 7 with same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

npm install attempts to download a package that violates the policy, developers will see an error similar to the following.

```
$ npm i lodash@1.0.0
npm notice Could not download lodash 1.0.0 due to policy violations. Use `npm audit fix` to upgrade this dependency.
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.npmjs.com/lodash/-/lodash-1.0.0.tgz
```

To fix this error, use npm audit fix to upgrade dependencies to versions that don't violate policy.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am doing fresh install. npm audit fix works on installed packages. And another thing, how it's working in Windows - 7?

Comment: its same you need to download nodejs from https://nodejs.org/en/ website then perform same command which you were done on window 10